# properties of System

Tags: signal-analysis, continuous-signals, homework, self-study

I am studying Signals and Systems. Anyone, please help me to answer the problems.

1. $y(t)=dx(t)/dt$ is time invariant:  True or False ?
2. $h(t)$ is the impulse response of an LTI system. If $h(t)$ is periodic and non-zero, the system is unstable:  True or False?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For question 1: [apply the definition of time invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-invariant_system): find the output as normal; find the output with the same input but delayed by $T$ 
$$
y_1(t) = \frac{dx(t)}{dt}\\
y_2(t) = \frac{dx(t-T)}{dt}\\
$$
Does $y_2(t) = y_1(t-T)$ ?

For question 2: Find a definition of stability and apply it. For example, for a system to be [BIBO stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability) it needs to have

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left|h(t)\right| dt < \infty
$$

If $h(t)$ is periodic and non-trivial (zero), can that be true?

Comment: Peter, for stability we require the $L_1$ norm to be finite, not the $L_2$ norm. E.g., an ideal low pass filter satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|h(t)|^2dt<\infty$, but it's not stable.

Comment: @MattL. D'oh! You are, as usual, correct! Thanks! Corrected.

Comment: 1) False, 2) True.. is that corect?

Comment: The Q1 statement being false means that if I take a derivative of a signal this morning it will give me one answer and then I take the derivative of a signal this afternoon it'll give me a different answer.

Comment: ohh Both are True.. right?

Comment: @PeterK. please confirm me this

Comment: @AadnanFarooqA: Correct!